# Detect programmatically if "Let Google apps access your location" disabled

Tags: android, location, google-apps

Does anyone know if you can check programmatically the state of "Let Google apps access your location?

I want to check if the option is disabled, and in that case, show "Google apps location settings" to let the user enable the opcion.

Google Apps Locations Settings *Screenshot* , this dialog is under "System settings" -> "Accounts" -> "Google"

[image]

Comment: Host the image's in a public image hosting site and provide just the link's here.

Comment: @HKane how did you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here You go you can do this by the following Code.

copy this method to where you are using google services

```
boolean servicesOK() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
                this, AtlastActivity.GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    } else {

    }
```

on where you want to check just do this

```
if(Servicesok(){
// DO SOMETHING

}else{
//DO Something Else
}
```

Comment: Here is GPS ErrorDialog Req  public static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

Comment: That code don't show the dialog that I'm looking for. Look at the image in the question.

Comment: This code checks if Google Play Services library is installed, but not if Google Play Services location is enabled or not...